# Как расположить надпись по координатам X и Y

Tags: java, swing

Вопрос в том что я не понял как работает расположение по координатам X и Y
Объясните пожалуйста
То что счёт идёт от ЛВ угла экрана я знаю и то что необходимо использовать данную строчку кода тоже знаю

```
labelX1.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(100, 100, 0, 0));
```

Comment: Этой инструкцией вы добавляете к надписи labelX1 пустую невидимую рамку. Толщина этой рамки сверху - 100px, слева - 100px, снизу - 0px, справа - 0px. В итоге получится, что ВИЗУАЛЬНО надпись сдвинется на 100 вниз и на 100 вправо.

Comment: `panel.setLayout(null); label.setBounds(...)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

panel.setLayout(null); label.setBounds(...) – [Stranger in the Q](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/188366/stranger-in-the-q)